# Is it possible to change constexpr-ops-limit inside the source file?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, constexpr, pragma

I want to change `constexpr-ops-limit` to a bigger number. I know that it is possible with `-fconstexpr-ops-limit=` as a command line argument, but I have no possibility to change arguments because I submit my code to a system that runs it automatically. I wonder if there are any pragmas in GCC or VC++ that will match my needs.

Is there any way to do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you really need to do more than 33 million operations in a constexpr (the default limit on GCC)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles when I wrote constexpr sin() and cos(), implemented by Taylor expansion and interpolation, I very much had to increase the limits.

Comment: I suspect that on a compiling webpage the limit might be set lower than the GCC default, precisely to stop people trying to get the compiler to generate   sin and cos tables using constexpr taylor series. I mean, how long does that thing take to compile @RichardHodges? :-)

Comment: @GemTaylor from memory, it took a fews tens of seconds. It was on my macbook.